# Wordpress User Management

Tags: wordpress

I need a little bit help with user management.
I have an education site (not ready yet), i need two registration:

First for students, they can register to courses with name, email, phone number etc.

Second for teachers, who can register with name, email, year of birth etc., but teachers can register for courses too.

But when a teacher wants to register for courses too, i want that she/he can use same email address, name etc. too. And i want it, after a teacher register both place, on the wp-admin/users i see just one registration.

There is any plugin which is easy to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can save registration data to wp_users and wp_user_meta. For student directly add data to wp_user_meta table of wordpress. For teacher regisrtation save on wp_post_meta for all courses. That is registered user for that course. It will be array of all user. Course id will be post id. 'register user' will be meta key. And at the time of registration update this meta with add user id to meta value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'no' there is no easy plugin for this. I'm DV the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that you not use Wordpress for this website and you consider building everything yourself. You are already hitting the constraints of Wordpress in that it is difficult to assign multiple roles and manage them consistently. I'm going to take another guess and say that even if you launch using Wordpress, you'll quickly outgrow it and need to rewrite your entire application.

If you build the application yourself, you can design the user database however you want and allow users to have one or more roles (i.e. student and/or teacher). Then your application can use the roles a user has to determine what to display to them.

If you want to reduce your overall dev time, piece together third-party APIs and tools. If you are using Node.js, check out Keystone.js (http://keystonejs.com), Hatch (http://hatchjs.com), and other CMS tools. You can also look for a user database like Passport (https://www.inversoft.com/products/user-database-sso) that give you a bunch of user management features. There are tons of free or open-source tools out there that can help you build this application quickly.